# Apache Spark container startup errors - Docker

Tags: docker, apache-spark

1. I downloaded apache spark docker image from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/spark/tags).
2. I then found out that `SPARK_NO_DAEMONIZE` should be set to `TRUE` - which I did by 'bash'ing into Docker using the following command

   ```
    docker run -ti --name spark apache/spark:v3.3.0 bash

    export SPARK_NO_DAEMONIZE=true
   ```
3. I then tried starting spark - '/opt/spark/sbin/start-master.sh' and then got the error

   ```
    sh-5.1$ /opt/spark/sbin/start-master.sh
    mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/spark/logs’: Permission denied
    chown: cannot access '/opt/spark/logs': No such file or directory
    starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to
      /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-   
      aaea1d8bfe7c.out
    Spark Command: /usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java -cp   
    /opt/spark/conf:/opt/spark/jars/* -Xmx1g 
    org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host aaea1d8bfe7c --port 7077 --  
    webui-port 8080
   ```

I understand from the 'Dockerfile' that user '185' runs everything in there. Unfortunately, I don't yet understand how to enable root user in there so that I can change the permissions or creating log directory.

Could someone please suggest whether I am missing something?

p.s. I don't wish to run spark using `docker-compose.yml` I want to run a single cluster

Comment: Try adding `user: root` after image in docker compose file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the user that runs inside the container:

```bash
docker run -ti --user 0 --name spark apache/spark:v3.3.0 bash
```

You are then root inside the container.

If you want to do it through a Dockerfile instead, these are the steps:

1. Create a Dockerfile as:

```
FROM apache/spark:v3.3.0

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /opt/spark/logs && chmod a+wr /opt/spark/logs

USER 185

ENV SPARK_NO_DAEMONIZE=true

CMD ["/opt/spark/sbin/start-master.sh"]
```

2. Build the image

```bash
docker build -t "testspark" .
```

3. Run the container

```bash
docker run -ti --rm testspark
```

Comment: This is what I would probably end up writing in my `Dockerfile` but I would also probably add some minor things such as nano :D